# Two different behaviors of the same Prolog code with and without debugging

Tags: debugging, prolog, swi-prolog, xpce

I am using the latets stable version 6.6.6 64 bit of SWI-Prolog for windows.
The code is following:

```
start :-
    new(Frame, frame('Test')),
    send(Frame, open),
    send(Frame, append, new(Pic, picture)),
    send(Pic, height, 600),
    send(Pic, display, new(_Ref1, text('This will disappear in 3 seconds', center, font(screen, roman, 16)))),
    sleep(3),
    send(Pic, clear),
    sleep(3),
    send(Pic, display, new(_Ref2, text('Good bye!', center, font(screen, roman, 16)))),
    sleep(2),
    send(Pic, clear).
```

The code does boring staff: 
It creates a window and a picture canvas on it with height 600px.
It displays a text that should disappear in 3 seconds, 
after 2 secs a new text appears that should disappear in 2 secs.

If I run it without debugging the first text disappears in 8 secs and that's all.

If I run with graphical debugging, the code does what it should (see the code description).

So my worries are for: why there is two different outcomes of the same code and why without debugging the code does not work as it should?

Comment: is it due to 6.6.6 version of the program? ^^

Comment: The difference is caused by lack of refresh of the canvas `Pic`.
So, if a cursor is moving over the picture canvas, then the text disappears and appears on it; otherwise the text is not disappeared.
Note that a cursor should be moving over the canvas, being over the canvas is not sufficient for the canvas refresh.
Quite unexpected behavior of the canvas object.

Comment: What is the proper code that will update the canvas itself?